# Checkbox not getting clicked on clicking label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The set up that I have is pretty straight forward and I know what's causing the issue for me.

Here is a fiddle of my work:  https://jsfiddle.net/ppw9b34u/

Its a collection of labels within a form. Now when you click on one of the labels, the corresponding input gets checked. However, if you click everything at a little faster rate. there is a high possibility that you will end up changing the colors of few labels without checking the input box.

What I observe is if I click a drag a little on any label. It colors it to red and not checks the checkbox. I have no Idea what do for such scenarios. Please help

I am also attaching the code below

html:

```
<div class="diag_options clearfix">
<form action="#" class="diag_options_form pap_answer">
                  <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-value="6" id="test6">
                    <label for="test6">Cardio Vascular Disease</label>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-value="7" id="test7">
                    <label for="test7" class="">Diabetes type 1</label>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-value="8" id="test8">
                    <label for="test8" class="">Diabetes type 2</label>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-value="9" id="test9">
                    <label for="test9" class="">Hypertension</label>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-value="10" id="test10">
                    <label for="test10" class="">Arthritis</label>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-value="11" id="test11">
                    <label for="test11" class="">Cancer</label>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-value="12" id="test12">
                    <label for="test12">Depression</label>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-value="13" id="test13">
                    <label for="test13" class="">High Cholesterol</label>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-value="190" id="test190">
                    <label for="test190" class="">Anemia</label>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-value="179" id="test179">
                    <label for="test179" class="">None of the above</label>
                  </p>
            </form>
            </div>
```

javascript:

```
 $(".diag_options p label").on("click",function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("none_opt")){
            $('.diag_options p label').removeClass("check");
            $(this).addClass("check");
        }
        else if($(this).hasClass("check")){
            $(this).removeClass("check");
        }
        else{
            $('.diag_options ul p label').removeClass("check");
            $(this).addClass("check");
        }
});
```

css:

```
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 4px 0 0;
}
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}
input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
.diag_options p {
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    width: 14.66%;
}

.diag_options p label {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    font-family: Roboto-Regular;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 125px;
    padding: 44px 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.pap_answer label {
    -moz-user-select: none;
}
.diag_options p label::before {
    content: "";
    display: none;
}
.check {
    background: #f98586 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
.check::after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/assets/paps_images/sprite_icon.svg") no-repeat scroll -110px 0 / auto 100%;
    content: "";
    height: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 22px;
}
```

Comment: Seems you're trying to code for *unreasonable user action*...that way lies madness.

Comment: I am not an expert, all I can say is that this case occured in a real testing scenario. The checkboxes there are a little bigger also . So obviously I am searching for a solution

Answer (score 2):

If you rely on the checkbox actually being checked, instead of clicking the label, you avoid any such problems

```
$(".diag_options p input").on("change",function(){
    $(this).next().toggleClass('check', this.checked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ppw9b34u/1/)